# How to use launchfiles in Eclipse for debugging

Tags: roslaunch, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to debug a particular node (openni_node) in Eclipse. To use that node normally one would call a launchfile like this: **`roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch`**, but this doesn't work on my computer at the moment ([link](http://answers.ros.org/question/326/openni_cameraopenni_nodelaunch-wont-start)).

Running roscore in terminal seems not to suffice to be able to then debug openni_node with Eclipse. Is there a way to use the same, aforementioned, launchfile in Eclipse in debug mode?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9369/how-to-use-launchfiles-in-eclipse-for-debugging/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could launch the node in debug mode by adding the following line to the  tag in the launch file: launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args" (see this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB)).  If you are not comfortable with a console based gdb you can use a front end interface like ddd.

You could configure Eclipse to use remote debugging, even if I think it's a long shot. You can find more instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81194/remote-debugging-with-eclipse-cdt).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4